# how to fill the default value of the "input" tag dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In my vote system, i have the `input tag` of the "expire_at".and what i want to do is that fill the `input tag` dynamically with the date.the date is 7days later.

For example ,if i do nothing with  "expire_at".it should be 2011-10-23 as default.(2011-10-16 with 7days later),how to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If +7 days is a default setting that applies everywhere, put it in your model:

In your model:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  def expires_at
    # I'm not sure if this works, if not
    # wrap it in a if-clause like:
    # read_attribute(:expires_at).present? ? read_attribute(:expires_at) : 7.days.from_now

    read_attribute(:expires_at) || 7.days.from_now
  end
end
```

In your view:

```
<%= f.text_field :expires_at, @vote.expires_at.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') %>
```

If it is only for one specific form, do it like in bricker's answer:
(without modifying your model of course)

In your view:

```
<%= f.text_field :expires_at, :value => (@vote.expires_at.present? ? @vote.expires_at : 7.days.from_now).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= f.text_field :expires_at, :value => @vote.new_record? ? Time.zone.now + 7.days : @vote.expires_at %>
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `new_record?` because if the validation fails, the user's input will be overwritten. So here's a modified version:

`<%= f.text_field :expires_at, :value => (@vote.expires_at.present? ? @vote.expires_at : 7.days.from_now).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') %>`